# JSSOR, dynamically and recursively loading folder contents into gallery?

Tags: javascript, html, image, jscript

Is there a way to search through a folder and load the entire folder contents (images) into JSSOR as an image gallery?

Additionally, the images will have to be resized to conform to the container (the images abide by a fixed aspect ratio but could vary in resolution).

I would like to stick to HTML/Jscript (no PHP etc) for the sake of the CMS build I'm using (CushyCMS).

The idea is that the editor simply points JSSOR at a folder and it dynamically pulls all the images out of the folder, into the slideshow gallery. The overall gallery will have a caption that is loaded from a TXT file, but images don't need individual captions on them.

The folder structure allows for sub-galleries, so when you go click an HTML link it would have to link to that folder. The tree could possibly look like...

Gallery

---> Gallery 1

------>image 1

------>image 2

------>image 3

------>caption.txt

--->Gallery 2

------>image 1

------>image 2

------>image 3

------>image 4

------>image 5

------>caption.txt

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is for fixing problems in your code, not a code generator.